# FormatterAssemblyStyle ambigous reference

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net

I have a `xamarin.androind` class library project. If I add `Json.net` nuget package to it and try to use FormatterAssemblyStyle got following error:

```
Error   102 The type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\dev\nuget.packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\portable-net40+sl4+wp7+win8\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

Project references json.net from folder `portable-net40+sl4+wp7+win8` and it really have 
`FormatterAssemblyStyle` in  `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` namespace.

I dont see how it can compile at all.